# Searching a class array with multiple values per record

Tags: java, arrays, oop, search, methods

I need to search an object array for a Name and then print out all info corresponding to that name.

I have

```
public class AccessFriendlyFile {
private Friendlies[] fr = new Friendlies[100];
private int size = 0;

public AccessFriendlyFile (){
try {
    Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("Friends.txt"));
    String line, name, surname, cell, mail, landline;

    while (scFile.hasNext()){
        line = scFile.nextLine();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");
        name = sc.next();
        surname = sc.next();
        cell = sc.next();

        if (sc.hasNext()){
            mail = sc.next();
            landline= sc.next();
            fr[size] = new ExtendFriendlies(name, surname, cell, mail, landline);

        }

        else {
            fr[size]= new Friendlies(name, surname, cell);
        }

        size++;
        sc.close();
    }

}catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

How do I code a method that will search "fr" for a name and print out all corresponding info?

Many Thanks
Jesse

Edit:
Here is my Search method, that is currently not working.

```
public int Search(String name) {
    int loop = 0;
    int pos = -1;
    boolean found = false;
    while (found == false) {
        if (fr[loop] == name) {
            found = true;
            pos = loop;
        } else {
            loop++;
        }
    }

    return pos;
}
```

Incomparable types error on the if statement.

Comment: With a loop. You already have a loop in your code, so you should know how they work. Is it homework? I so, please add the homework tag. Any reason why you don't use collections instead of arrays?

Comment: Not homework, trying to understand how to do it, is all. I will get there, moving my way up slowly. I will edit to show the search method I have been able to come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you rename your variables here.  The Friendlies class stores, I think, a single contact, a Friend.  The list of Friend objects is an array that you might beter name friendList or even friendlies.  I would also encourage you to not use size as a counter variable.  Size is how many friends you have, and you can iterate through them using i, or friendCounter, or use a for each loop as I demonstrate below,

```
public Friendlies find(String name) {
    for(Friendlies friend : fr) {
        if(friend.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return fiend;
    }
    return null;

}

//now to print the info you can do this:
Friendlies findJoe = find("Joe");
if(findJoe==null)
    System.out.println("You have no friends namd Joe.");
else
    System.out.println(findJoe);
```

My code assumes that you implement toString() in Friendlies.  If you use netbeans, you can auto-generate this code and then tweak it to get the format you want. (Just right-click where you want to write the method and choose insert code)

Comment: google guava's Objects.toStringHelper is neat for implementing toString methods.

Comment: I have implemented a toString(). Thanks for the tips. This makes sense and I achieved what I wanted to achieve, but, for interests sake, how would I return the Friend as well as his position in the array?

Comment: You could encapsulte the Fiend in a class that contain a friend and a int representing the position. you could also return a tuple object that would look like a Pair<Friend,Integer>

Answer (score 1):

In your `Friendlies` class, have a method called `getName()` that will return the name of that Friendly. Iterate through the `fr` until you find the matching name. Once you've found that name, use similar `get` methods to print out all the information you want for the matching `Friendly` you just found.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public List<Friendlies> search(String name) {

    List<Friendlies> list = new ArrayList<Friendlies>();
    for(Friendlies friendlies : fr) {
        if(friendlies.getName().equals(name)) {
            list.add(friendlies);
        }
    }

    return list;

}
```

Then, with the returned list, implement a nice display of the data :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the AccessFriendlyFile  loads the data into your array, you can use a for each loop, if you want to retieve all the matching names :

```
List<Friendlies> getByName(String searched){
   List<Friendlies> result = new Arraylist<Friendlies>();
   for (Friendlies currentFriendly : fr){
      if (searched.equalsIgnoreCase(currentFriendly.getName()){
        result.add(currentFriendly);
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

for only the first one :

```
Friendlies getByName(String searched){
   for (Friendlies currentFriendly : fr){
      if (searched.equalsIgnoreCase(currentFriendly.getName()){
        return currentFriendly;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

You should use lists instead of fixed arrays. If the files contains more than 100 records you'll get an indexoutofbounds exception.